# Changing images in imageview

Tags: android

I have made an android app that changes images in imageview after 5secs.However the images are superimposed on the image that is selected when imageview is created.I don't want that image.Kindly help,here is the code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int count;
    int images[] = { R.drawable.c1, 
            R.drawable.c12,
            R.drawable.c3, 
            R.drawable.c4,
            R.drawable.c5, 
            R.drawable.c6,
            R.drawable.c7 };
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 

        handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000);
    }
    Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (count >6) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
            } else {

                if (count >= 6)
                    count = 0;
                AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f); //here is a bit of animation for ya ;)
                animation1.setDuration(5000);
                animation1.setStartOffset(1300); //time for that color effect
                animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                imageView.startAnimation(animation1);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[count++]);
                handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000);
                }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.change.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="206dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added imageView.setImageDrawable(null) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[count++]);
```

try

```
imageView.setImageResource(images[count++]);
```